# Xero BankTransfers won't show up

Tags: xero-api

I'm using BankTransfers endpoint to add transfers between bank accounts. It used to work like a charm in the past. I did not make any changes to my code, but transfers suddenly stopped to appear. Xero responds with 200 code and status OK but transfers just won't show up. Also, TransferID looks like this for some reason:

```
"BankTransferID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
```

ValidationErrors is empty so it seems that the transfer is accepted as valid, but won't show up in any of the accounts involved.

Transfer body I use looks like this:

```
{
                "BankTransfers": [{
                    "FromBankAccount": {"Code": transfer_from },
                    "ToBankAccount": {"Code": transfer_to},
                    "Date": transaction_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                    "Amount": amount}]}
```

And response looks like this:

```
{
  "Id": "1d28fdb6-cadf-4f4c-9801-55b47567e87d",
  "Status": "OK",
  "ProviderName": app_name_hidden,
  "DateTimeUTC": "\/Date(1628847828463)\/",
  "BankTransfers": [
    {
      "BankTransferID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "DateString": "2021-08-13T00:00:00",
      "Date": "\/Date(1628812800000+0000)\/",
      "FromBankAccount": {
        "AccountID": account_id_hidden,
        "Code": "1057",
        "Name": account_name
      },
      "ToBankAccount": {
        "AccountID": account_id_hidden_2,
        "Code": "1073",
        "Name": account_name_2
      },
      "Amount": 1000.00,
      "FromBankTransactionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "ToBankTransactionID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "CurrencyRate": 1.0000000000,
      "ValidationErrors": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Did anyone face the same issue? Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: This is not a Python issue. If your code worked previously and you haven't changed it then the problem must surely be related to the Xero API implementation

Comment: I'm using python for making requests, so I though the flag is appropriate. Removed it now not to confuse others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our developers made a release that fix this issue.

Apologies for the inconvenience caused